# php long Table of Contents displayd from database (loop issue)

Tags: php

I have long Table of Contents i need to set position with html but i do not wanna repeat MySQL command every time i need to display content...

my code look like that:

```
<h4 class="quizcenter" id="kard">Kardio</h4></br>
  <div class="kard">
    <ol>
    <?php 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM contents";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck>0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $main = $row['main'];
            $id = $row['type'];
            $sub= $row['sub'];
             if($row['main']=='Kardio'){
              echo "<li id='{$id}'>{$sub}</li>";
             } 
          }  
        }
    ?>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <hr>
```

Code above working but... my long content look like that:

```
<h4 class="quizcenter" id="kard">Kardio</h4></br>
  <div class="kard">
   <ol>
<!-- php output like in code above-->
   </ol>
  </div>
  <hr>
<h4 class="quizcenter" id="pulm">Pulmo</h4></br>
  <div class="pulm">
   <ol>
<!-- php output like in code above-->
   </ol>
  </div>
<hr>
```

Already try separate html with php, and put if statement between each ol but that generate me html code so many times like in loop.

I will be glad if someone will share a solution with me :D